Vertex color interpolation issue on edges
I've been using blender to procedurally make terrain for a video game I am working on in Unreal engine. I want to use vertex colors as a way to interpolate between different textures on unreal. Worth noting that my texturing is "tile-based" in a style not too different from minecraft with the addition of blending between tile textures.
My issue is when coloring vertices in a corner style, there seems to be improper blending in the middle along the diagonal. As an example:

In this image, the bottom left vertex is white and the other 3 are black. The quad is also split into tris as such:

I know that vertex colors are per tri, and I've already painted vertices the same color in both tris but I still cannot tell why the blending is off.
I've considered adding more tris but that doesn't eliminate the problem, only makes it smaller and I cannot afford to over-poly these tiles as it would over complicate the procedural generation of the terrain.
My research tells me this is an issue with how vertex colors are interpolated which ties my hands in trying to fix it. I did a quick test on Matlab to interpolated based on 4 vertices and the result is the blend I am looking for:

However, blender and unreal only interpolate based on 3 vertex triangles. With all that in mind, I'm not really sure how I can achieve this so I'd appreciate any pointers or ideas whether it uses vertex colors or anything else. Thanks in advance!

Do you know the algorithm matlab uses for this interpolation? In the end of the day what you will need is triangulate yourself, store corners of the triangle for each vertex, and also store the corner outside the triangle. I think this is a good start: How to reproduce Blender's smooth shading?

I wrote the interpolation on matlab myself, its just a simple bilinear interpolation but using 4 vertices which is kinda impossible in blender/unreal because the interpolation is done behind closed curtains as far as I know, and it only uses 3 verts. I've been trying to think of a way to reverse-calculate what the values of each of 3 verts could be so that it emulates the same effect but haven't figured it out yet
